# iphone .pls parser

Tags: iphone, playlist

how to access the .pls and .qtl file content from web using objective c.

Comment: This is a bit vague. What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an NSURLConnection to download the files.  Processing a [PLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29) file should be straight forward since it's basically a text file.